# How to improve laravel routing?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am working on some ecommerce project in laravel framework where my category route is below:-

```
Route::get('/category/{catname}', 'SearchController@searchCatProducts');
```

When i access website its working like this:-

```
www.example.com/category/men
```

But our client wants it should like this :-

```
www.example.com/men
```

if i create Roue like:-

```
Route::get('/{catname}', 'SearchController@searchCatProducts');
and other routes will also reflect like aboutus, contactus,
Route::get('/aboutus', 'CMScontroller@aboutus');
```

Can anyone help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about adding some postfix?

Comment: `www.example.com/men-cat`

Comment: how about implementing a middleware for cases like this?

Comment: @BonishKoirala please post answer in detail.. it will be helpful

Comment: IMO it's better to leave this as it is and change using .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

You must change the order.

```
Route::get('/aboutus', 'CMScontroller@aboutus');
Route::get('/{catname}', 'SearchController@searchCatProducts');
```

put the static routes to the top.
dynamic route to the bottom.

Comment: what about products.... if i want to show product like :- www.example.com/black-men-tshirt with having different function name

Comment: You can try the order logic with 2 sample. Order should like this sir. If you put the dynamically route to the top. Like you did. All one parameter routes go this {catname}. You should put this to bottom of the routes. Please test this twice, give it a try.

Comment: what about product detail  page? Route::get('/{product}', 'ProductsController@productetail');

Comment: You can't separate them in the route file. There is no way. Even if you are using routes name in the view. You must separate this in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
Route::get('/{catname}', 'SearchController@searchCatProducts');

Route::get('/frontend/aboutus', 'CMScontroller@aboutus');
Route::get('/frontend/contactus', 'CMScontroller@contactus');
```